# how gradientboosting decision tree in scikit-learn do prediction

Tags: scikit-learn, boosting, ensemble-learning

I am using Gradient Boosting Decision Tree to do binary classification, the following is my code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("../data/data.csv", header=0)

X = data.iloc[:,1:-1]
y = data.iloc[:,0]

gbdt = GradientBoostingClassifier(criterion='friedman_mse', init=None,
          learning_rate=0.1, loss='deviance', max_depth=3,
          max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
          min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
          min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
          n_estimators=90, presort='auto', random_state=None,
          subsample=1.0, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

gbdt.fit(X, y)
```

After the fit method, I try to plot all the Decision Trees. The following is my code:

```
import pydotplus
from sklearn import tree

for i in range(gbdt.estimators_.shape[0]):
    dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(gbdt.estimators_[i][0], out_file=None) 
    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data) 
    graph.write_pdf("../data/trees/tree_"+str(i)+".pdf")
```

I get 90 Decision Trees, the first one is as follows:
[image]

I do not know how did it construct all the trees. Also, what does the friedman_mse and value in each node mean? And how to compute them? If I got a new sample with its attribute X, how to do the prediction according to all the trees?

Comment: You mention that you know how gradient boosting works, but then follow up with some foundational things you don't know about it.  It would be helpful if you listed the things you already understand about gradient boosting.

Comment: I mean I do not know how they are  realized in scikit-learn. Because there are many tutorial about the gradient boosting, but there is not much details about it, so I would appreciate it if you know how it is  realized in scikit-learn? Thank you~

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have not understood how did GBDT works. What I know is that the GBDT will construct the tree with the residual from the last decision tree as well as the CART algorithm. The tutorial in the network says the trees was constructed by CART algorithm, but it seems that is not the case.